Are the animals in "The Wild Robot" normal?
In the film The Wild Robot, the titular character spends quite some time analyzing the speech of wild animals and is then able to communicate with them. The animals seem to show complex thought and relationships, basically on the level of humans.
Of course, this is not particularly uncommon in movies with animal characters. However, there is some evidence hinting at a relatively far-future setting, such as the Golden Gate Bridge being underwater (i.e. over 200 feet of sea level rise), all non-futuristic cities looking like ancient ruins, and so forth, so another distinct possibility is that the animals are not meant to be the same as their modern-day counterparts, but rather have evolved to be smarter or something similar.
Are the animals in the film supposed to be bog-standard modern animals, or are they different for some setting-related reason?

There is one line that definitively answered this question for me, but only after understanding the final theme at the end: Roz was an ordinary ROZZUM-type robot that learned to be more than her programming, physically so ordinary that all her parts were replaced at the end while she was still able to keep her function. Similarly, there was nothing special about these animals except that Roz and Brightbill taught them to be more than their instincts:

I know you all have instincts that keep you alive, but at some times, to survive, we must become more than we were programmed to be.

